# html css loading animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I was following an online tutorial based on a video on a link below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttWXapXj4cg

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #042104;
    animation: animateBg 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animateBg
{
    0%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
section .loader
{
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
section .loader span
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(calc(18deg * var(--i)));
}
section .loader span::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #00ff0a;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00ff0a,
                0 0 20px #00ff0a,
                0 0 40px #00ff0a,
                0 0 60px #00ff0a,
                0 0 80px #00ff0a,
                0 0 100px #00ff0a;
    animation: animate 2s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--1));
}
@keyframes animate
{
    0%
    {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    80%,100%
    {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CSS creative Loader Animation Effects</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="loader">
            <span style="--i:1"></span>
            <span style="--i:2"></span>
            <span style="--i:3"></span>
            <span style="--i:4"></span>
            <span style="--i:5"></span>
            <span style="--i:6"></span>
            <span style="--i:7"></span>
            <span style="--i:8"></span>
            <span style="--i:9"></span>
            <span style="--i:10"></span>
            <span style="--i:11"></span>
            <span style="--i:12"></span>
            <span style="--i:13"></span>
            <span style="--i:14"></span>
            <span style="--i:15"></span>
            <span style="--i:16"></span>
            <span style="--i:17"></span>
            <span style="--i:18"></span>
            <span style="--i:19"></span>
            <span style="--i:20"></span>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

The code was supposed to show A loading animation that shows an array of circles rotating clockwise just like in the video, but it's not. I would like to know what I did wrong, i would please appreciate that. pLease and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, looks like you had a typo.

```
section .loader span::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #00ff0a;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00ff0a,
                0 0 20px #00ff0a,
                0 0 40px #00ff0a,
                0 0 60px #00ff0a,
                0 0 80px #00ff0a,
                0 0 100px #00ff0a;
    animation: animate 2s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--1));
}
```

In the animation-delay you said calc(0.1s * var(--1)); But is supposed to be like this:

```
section .loader span::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #00ff0a;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00ff0a,
                0 0 20px #00ff0a,
                0 0 40px #00ff0a,
                0 0 60px #00ff0a,
                0 0 80px #00ff0a,
                0 0 100px #00ff0a;
    animation: animate 2s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
}
```

So var(--i) instead of var(--1).

Have fun with it ;)

Comment: What I meant is that I want it to rotate clockwise just like in the tutorial video on youtube.

Comment: I know and that is it doing, I fixed it, just copy the css of my example.